# Ionic3 coding- trying to retrieve quote of the day

Tags: json, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Code in `provider.ts` file :

```
getQuotes() : Observable<any> {  
    return this.http.get(""); 
}
```

1st method: The coding in `home.ts` file of the page where the quote needs to be displayed:

```
quote:string;
author:string;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private qp: QuoteProvider) { }

ionViewDidLoad()
{
   this.qp.getQuotes().subscribe(data => {
      this.quote = data.quote;
      this.author = data.author;      
   });
}
```

`.html` code tried this nothing worked:

```
<h2> {{ quote}} </h2>
<h3> {{ author }}</h3>
</ion-item>    </ion-list>
```

2nd method tried; tried using array though the data is not in array format
`home.ts` file:

```
export class HomePage {  quote:any[];  author:any[];    
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private qp: QuoteProvider) {  }

ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.qp.getQuotes().subscribe(data => {
       this.quote = data.quotes;
       this.author = data.quotes;
    });  
}
```

`.html` file code*:

```
<ion-list>
   <ion-item *ngFor = "let q of quote">

      <h2> {{ q.quote}} </h2>
      <h3> {{q.author }}</h3>
   </ion-item>    
</ion-list>
```

Comment: >ionViewDidLoad() {
 >   this.qp.getQuotes().subscribe(data => {
  >  this.quote = data.contents.quotes.quote;
  >   this.author = data.contents.quotes.author;
> });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `provider.ts` you should do the following:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

getQuotes(){
   return this.http.get("").map(res => res.json());

}
```

Then in `home.ts`

```
ionViewDidLoad()
{
  this.qp.getQuotes().subscribe(data => {
    this.quote = data.contents.quotes[0].quote;
    this.author = data.contents.quotes[0].author;   
    // This is assuming the quotes array always has only one quote
  });
}
```

**EDIT**
As [Prerak Tiwari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3326169/prerak-tiwari)  commented, you also need to remove the for loop in `home.html`:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <h2> {{ quote }} </h2>
    <h3> {{ author }}</h3>
  </ion-item>    
</ion-list>
```

Comment: he needs to remove for loop from html too.

Comment: @san You need to add `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`  to your service provider so it can work

Comment: I edited the question to reflect what you have to do

Comment: @san Thing is you have the wrong address, in my answer you can see I use quote.rest/qod.json. The error is that you have quote.rest/qod/json instead of quote.rest/qod.json

Comment: @san I think you need more rep to open a chat room, i do as well. What do you need help with?

Comment: @san I can't create chats neither

Comment: @san reputation